# Layout for Client/Server project with common code

Tags: python, client-server

I'm working on a client/server application in Python, where client and server share a lot of code.
How should the folder structure look like?

My idea is to have three folders with the code files in it

- server

  - server.py
  - etc.
- client

  - client.py
  - etc.
- common

  - common.py
  - etc.

But how can I import from common.py in server.py when server.py has to be executable (can't be a package)?

Currently we have all files in the same folder but since the project got more complex this isn't manageable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to have the executable scripts all at the top folder like this:

- server

  - server specific code
- client

  - client specific code
- common

  - common code
- server.py (executable script that imports from server and common)
- client.py (executable script that imports from client and common)

When deploying the server I just copy server.py, the server and the common folder. Similar for the client.

It's not the ideal solution and I'd be thankful if someone comes up with a better one but that is how I use it now.